# In a Visual Studio C# project, is it possible to enforce Microsoft Learn's Best Practice Naming convention for tests?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, coding-style, editorconfig

[Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-best-practices) suggests the best way to name unit test methods is like `Add_SingleNumber_ReturnsSameNumber`.

I would like to force project contributors to follow this convention, making it an error if the name does not have all three parts.

However, presently naming test methods this way results in a violation of CA1707.

While I can use GlobalSuppressions to suppress this with:

```
[assembly: SuppressMessage("Naming", "CA1707:Identifiers should not contain underscores", Justification = "<Pending>", Scope = "module")]
```

that's not really what I want to do since it still allows tests to have incorrect names.

A colleague suggested to try adding the following to .editorconfig:

```
dotnet_naming_rule.test_method_names.rule = ^[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*(_[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$
dotnet_naming_rule.test_method_names.symbols = testMethodName
dotnet_naming_rule.test_method_names.style = camel_case
dotnet_naming_rule.test_method_names.severity = suggestion
dotnet_naming_rule.test_method_names.title = Test method names should be in camelCase and start with an uppercase letter
dotnet_naming_rule.test_method_names.description = Test method names should be in camelCase and start with an uppercase letter
dotnet_naming_rule.test_method_names.where = dotnet_test_methods
```

However, Visual Studio seemed to ignore this.

We later added

```
dotnet_code_quality.CA1707.exclude = dotnet_test_methods

dotnet_naming_rule.methods_should_not_have_underscores.rule = ^[^_]*$
dotnet_naming_rule.methods_should_not_have_underscores.symbols = methodName
dotnet_naming_rule.methods_should_not_have_underscores.style = identifier_style
dotnet_naming_rule.methods_should_not_have_underscores.severity = suggestion
dotnet_naming_rule.methods_should_not_have_underscores.title = Method names should not contain underscores
dotnet_naming_rule.methods_should_not_have_underscores.description = Method names should not contain underscores
dotnet_naming_rule.methods_should_not_have_underscores.where = dotnet_symbols_without_parameters and !dotnet_test_methods
```

But this was also ignored by Visual Studio.

Is there anything I can/should do to make this work?

Comment: Hello, have you installed the latest version of the .Net SDK?

Comment: I have version 7.0.200, commit 534117727b

Comment: The idea of adding a naming convention to the .editorconfig file is correct. But you need to use a code analysis tool, what is the code analysis tool you use?

Comment: I'm just using the code analysis built into Visual Studio 2022.  Is there some plugin I can/should be using?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot recommend third-party products to you due to some requirements. This is up to you to find out. If your Issue is still not resolved, please let me know.

Comment: Without endorsing third-party products can you at least _name_ some that I should look at, preferably some which aren't going to come with costs or licensing issues which may prevent me from using them?

Comment: You can refer here. https://github.com/JosefPihrt/Roslynator/issues/91

Answer (score 1):

The suggestions you received from your colleagues are in a syntax which does not make sense. It resembles the syntax for defining naming rules in .editorconfig, but it is not quite it. For example, the syntax as I know it has no provision for describing identifiers using regular expressions. Also, there is no such thing as "dotnet_test_methods" in the list of things that can be excluded.

As you have already discovered, Microsoft's implementation of .editorconfig in Visual Studio works under a totalitarian regime of silent failure, which means that if Visual Studio fails to understand a line in your .editorconfig file, then that line will be ignored, and you will not be given the slightest error, warning, indication, or hint that it was ignored. (Your only hint will be that whatever you were trying to accomplish will not be accomplished.)

<sup>`<rant>`It is my firm belief that any individual or group, organization, or government that in any way implements, propagates, or otherwise promotes any form of silent failure ***SHOULD BE SHOT***, but I digress.`</rant>`</sup>

So, the syntax you were given is wrong. The correct syntax is explained here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/naming-rules

Just to keep things interesting, there is also this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1707

... and microsoft has left it entirely unclear how the two relate to each other, but it is a safe bet to assume (as you have already discovered) that if you start defining naming rules to control the use of underscore, then you probably want to begin by disabling CA1707.

Adding insult to injury, the .editorconfig syntax of `property = value` is not suitable for something as complex as defining naming rules, but they went ahead anyway and shoe-horned naming rule definition into the .editorconfig syntax, resulting in a naming rule definition mechanism which is very complex, unintuitive, and hard to get right. (Which, together with silent failure, forms a deadly combination.)

The link to the naming rules that I gave explains them in a formal style, which might be suitable for official reference material, but is hard to make sense of; so here is a quick reference which is more geared towards quickly grasping it:

```
# General syntax for defining naming rules:
#
# dotnet_naming_style.<StyleName>.capitalization = one of: pascal_case, camel_case, first_word_upper, all_upper, all_lower
# dotnet_naming_style.<StyleName>.required_prefix = <string>
# dotnet_naming_style.<StyleName>.required_suffix = <string>
# dotnet_naming_style.<StyleName>.word_separator = <string>
#
# dotnet_naming_symbols.<SymbolsName>.applicable_kinds = one of: *, namespace, class, struct, interface, enum, property, method, field, event, delegate, parameter, type_parameter, local, local_function
# dotnet_naming_symbols.<SymbolsName>.applicable_accessibilities = one of: *, public, internal or friend, private, protected, protected_internal or protected_friend, private_protected, local
# dotnet_naming_symbols.<SymbolsName>.required_modifiers = one of: abstract or must_inherit, async, const, readonly, static or shared
#
# dotnet_naming_rule.<RuleName>.style = <StyleName>
# dotnet_naming_rule.<RuleName>.symbols = <SymbolsName>
# dotnet_naming_rule.<RuleName>.severity = one of: error, warning, suggestion, silent, none, default
#
# NOTE: You must specify a capitalization style as part of your naming style, otherwise your naming style might be ignored.
```

The only way I have found to make certain naming rules apply to tests and only to tests is to define those naming rules in a `[*Tests.cs]` section, and then to make sure that all of your source files that contain test methods end in `...Tests.cs`.  It is clunky, but it kind of works.